# Count duplicate records between two pattern

Tags: python, linux, perl

I want to count duplicate records between two pattern and print them next to pattern one and two.

### INPUT

> Cluster 1
>   one
>   one
>   two
>   two
>   two
>   Cluster 2
>   two
>   one
>   one
>   two
>   Cluster 3
>   one
>   Cluster 4
>   two
>   two
>   one

### OUTPUT

> Cluster 1 2 3
>   Cluster 2 2 2
>   Cluster 3 1 0
>   Cluster 4 1 2

I have tried awk but it just count lines between Cluster, not the duplicates.

i have tried this code ;.....

```
cut -d _ -f2 norm_nonnorm_merged-95-count-new.clstr | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1>1&&$0=$2 " - " $1 " times"'
```

it print

```
one - 6 times
two - 7 times
```

Also tried

```
awk ' />Cluster/ { if ( f!="") {print f-1}; f=0;f1=1 } f1 { f++ } ' norm_nonnorm_merged-95.clstr
```

it prints

```
5
4
1
3
```

Comment: _I am new to this forum_: Take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Are you using Python or Perl?

Comment: show us what you did in awk. Maybe we can fix that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Python:

```
txt='''\
Cluster 1
one
one
two
two
two
Cluster 2
two
one
one
two
Cluster 3
one
Cluster 4
two
two
one
'''

import re

for t in re.findall(r'(Cluster \d)(.*?)(?=Cluster|$)', txt, re.S):
    print t[0],t[1].count('one'), t[1].count('two')
```

Prints:

```
Cluster 1 2 3
Cluster 2 2 2
Cluster 3 1 0
Cluster 4 1 2
```

---

(not tested...)

```
import re

fn1='one.txt'
fn2='two.txt'
fn3='one-two.txt'

with open(fn1, 'w') as f1, open(fn2, 'w') as f2, open(fn3, 'w') as f3:
    for t in re.findall(r'(Cluster \d+)(.*?)(?=Cluster|$)', txt, re.S):
        one=t[1].count('one')
        two=t[1].count('two')
        out= '{} {} {}\n'.format(t[0], one, two)
        if one and two:
            f3.write(out)
        elif one:
            f1.write(out)
        elif two:
            f2.write(out)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the code. I have modified a bit (\d+) and It works fine. Is it possible to save the output to 3 files. One.txt (two=0), Two.txt (one=0) and One-Two.txt (both > 0).

Answer (score 1):

A longer form perl script solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %allkeys;
my @clusters;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^Cluster/) {
        push @clusters, [$_, {}];
    } else {
        $clusters[-1][1]{$_}++;
        $allkeys{$_}++;
    }
}

my @sortedkeys = sort keys %allkeys;
for my $cluster (@clusters) {
    print "$cluster->[0] " . join(' ', map {$cluster->[1]{$_} // 0} @sortedkeys) . "\n";
}


__DATA__
Cluster 1
one
one
two
two
two
Cluster 2
two
one
one
two
Cluster 3
one
Cluster 4
two
two
one
```

Outputs:

```
Cluster 1 2 3
Cluster 2 2 2
Cluster 3 1 0
Cluster 4 1 2
```

Comment: Many thanks for the code. It works fine. Is it possible to save the output to 3 files. One.txt (two=0), Two.txt (one=0) and One-Two.txt (both > 0).